# Gitk can't read treediffs error

Tags: git, gitk

I got the following error when launching gitk > View > New View > Select All refs > OK :

```
can't read "treediffs(23eda73bba89ba7de9605f28f124fa7d9d67528f)": no such variable
can't read "treediffs(23eda73bba89ba7de9605f28f124fa7d9d67528f)": no such variable
    while executing
"lsearch -exact $treediffs($ids) $fname"
    (procedure "makediffhdr" line 7)
    invoked from within
"makediffhdr $fname $ids"
    (procedure "getblobdiffline" line 60)
    invoked from within
"getblobdiffline file8 23eda73bba89ba7de9605f28f124fa7d9d67528f"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $script"
    (procedure "dorunq" line 11)
    invoked from within
"dorunq"
    ("after" script)
```

I'm using git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0. I notice that this only happens on a current branch whose HEAD is a very large commit (many files and line changes). Once I switch to a different branch whose HEAD is a smaller commit, this issue does not appear. It seems like a gitk bug where it cannot read a large commit to do a treediffs. I am wondering if other people are having same problem, know a good line limits for each commit, or have other solutions.

Comment: Git for Windows 1.7.3.1 was released on 2 Oct 2010. First, try the current version.

Comment: @patthoyts reproduced with Git 2.26.0.windows.1 - The bundled Gitk show's me "Copyright (c) 2005-2016" which leads me to think we shouldn't expect a fix anytime soon. Anyone [fluent in tcl](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/gitk-git/gitk) by the way?

Comment: seven years and still  a bug... 
I tried to clone such a repo, hoping that the problem would go away by the recreation of the new repo, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Same happend to me. I added an existing project with a huge amount of files.
gitk crashed.
Then I made a small cange in one of the project files, commited and pushed.
gitk did not crash any more.